# How make paginate in template page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a problem. I can not create a paging on a wordpress template page. I created a pagination in the file, now when I create a template on the page it did not work, has anyone gone through this? I'm creating a "custom paging" and it brings everything but does not work the links.

Where the pagination will be displayed:

```
<?php $paginate_links = $leitura_controller->custom_pagination($leituras->max_num_pages,"");
        if ($paginate_links) : ?>
            <nav class='custom-pagination'>
                <?php echo $paginate_links; ?>
            </nav>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

controller function:

```
public function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '') {

        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        if (empty($pagerange)) {
            $pagerange = 2;
        }

        global $paged;
        if (empty($paged)) {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        if ($numpages == '') {
            global $wp_query;
            $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$numpages) {
                $numpages = 1;
            }
        }

        return $paginate_links = $this->leitura_model->custom_pagination($numpages, $pagerange, $paged);
    }
```

model function:

```
public function custom_pagination($numpages, $pagerange, $paged) {
        $pagination_args = array(
            'base'            => @add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
            'format'          => 'page/%#%',
            'total'           => $numpages,
            'current'         => $paged,
            'show_all'        => False,
            'end_size'        => 1,
            'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
            'prev_next'       => True,
            'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
            'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
            'type'            => 'plain',
            'add_args'        => false,
            'add_fragment'    => ''
        );

        return paginate_links($pagination_args);
    }
```

**what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Use mysql query

Comment: sorry, can explain?